# Why is this variable messed up after a function call

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class KeyT, class ValueT>
struct KeyValuePair {
  const KeyT &key_;
  const ValueT &value_;

  KeyValuePair() {
    cout << "KeyValuePair() constructor" << endl;
  }

  KeyValuePair( const KeyValuePair<KeyT, ValueT> &other) {
    cout << "KeyvaluePiar copy constructor" << endl;
  }

  KeyValuePair(KeyT key, ValueT value) : key_(key), value_(value) {
    cout << "KeyValuePair(KeyT, ValueT) constructor" << " key_: " << key_ << " value_ " << value_ << endl;
  }

  ~KeyValuePair() {}
};

struct foo {
 int i;
};

void dump(const KeyValuePair<int, foo*> &kp) {
  //printf("dump printf key: %d, value: %p\n", kp.key_, kp.value_);
  cout << "dump cout key_: " << kp.key_ << " value_: " << kp.value_ << " i: " << (kp.value_)->i << "\n";
}

int main() {
  cout << "test kv\n";
  foo *ptr = new foo();
  ptr->i = 3000;
  printf("address of ptr: %p\n", ptr);
  dump(KeyValuePair<int, foo*>(10, ptr));
  return 0;
}
```

Run it with

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -fPIC -O0 -o main main.cc && ./main
```

on a **Linux machine**.

In the above c++ example code gives the following result

```
test kv
address of ptr: 0x18a1010
KeyValuePair(KeyT, ValueT) constructor key_: 10 value_ 0x18a1010
dump cout key_: 10 value_: 0x7fffae060070 i: -1375338428
```

It seems that KeyValuePair's value_ is messed up after calling dump function, anyone knows the reason? It seems to be related to reference and pointers.

Comment: I'm confident that your compiler already told you all about the numerous problems with the shown code. Even though the compiler reluctantly compiled the shown code, those warning messages have a good reason behind them. Don't ignore warning messages from your compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your member variable is a reference:

```
const KeyT &key_;
```

Your constructor, on the other hand, passes by value:

```
KeyValuePair(KeyT key, ValueT value)
```

That means you are storing a reference to a temporary variable that will get destroyed almost immediately.

---

One solution would be to pass by reference in your constructor:

```
KeyValuePair(KeyT& key, ValueT& value)
```

which is better, but not perfect, since you pass a int literal `10` into the function.

If you really  just need a pair, the best solution is probably to use [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).